# Possible to match at one position of regex but not another (e.g. positional XOR)?

Tags: .net, regex, regex-lookarounds, balancing-groups

I am looking to create several sub-expressions in a larger regular expression, where each subexpression matches something at one place in the input or another place, but not in both places, preferably using the same named group per "area of interest". For example, I'd like to match volume units in *italics* below, and currency units, shown in **bold**.

- $3.23 **USD** / *gal*.
- **USD** 3.23 in *gallons*
- 4.50 **CAD** / *gal*
- 1 *gal* @ **USD** 3.23
- 10 *gal*. @ $4.50 **CAD**

Or more generally:

- *stuffmorestuff***XXX***yetmorestuff*
- *stuff***XXX***morestuff*

where *stuff* and *morestuff* could be a complex set of sub-expressions.

It seems like it might be possible using some combination of

- group stack push/pop
- balancing groups
- look-around

but I'm not sure how to proceed. Does it come down to alternations (`|`) or multiple passes with different expressions (which I suppose amounts to the same thing)?

Comment: You'll need better examples. In the three that you show, your regular expression is simply `"XXX"`. Or, I suppose `"USD|CAD"`. Give a few examples where that won't do what you want.

Comment: @Kit you will probably have to take into account all possible conditions for this to work.

Comment: In your first example, there doesn't seem to be any need for the regex to specify different units: if they come out the same then the conversion is easy.

Comment: The units are only a part of it. There are many other named captures, which seem to prevent a single capture in multiple positions.

Comment: @JimMischel - I added two more examples and added some detail explaining I'm really looking to do this multiple times (i.e. multiple named groups in different places).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to use alternation, something like this?

```
^(stuffmorestuff)XXX(yetmorestuff)|(stuff)XXX(morestuff)$
```

But you will end up with four capture groups. Not sure how the .NET regex engine will behave if you use the same group name for several groups.

Comment: .NET gives you complete freedom to reuse group names, so that's not problem.

Comment: Yes, the names can be reused. What happens is more than one value can be stored.